# AWS Sentinel 2 incorrect cloudy pixel percentage

Tags: tiles, sentinel-2, pixel, cloud-cover, amazon-web-services

For some tiles with low data coverage percentage metadata and tileInfo contain cloudy pixel percentage value equal 0.

Examples:

http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/37/U/DP/2017/10/14/0/
http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/37/U/DP/2017/4/17/0

Is cloud coverage calculated only for scenes with data coverage larger than some value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a known anomaly - see anomaly #29 in the Sentinel 2 data quality report.
https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-quality-report

Comment: Is there a quick way to filter such tiles without downloading gml mask?

Answer (score 3):

Seninel 2's Technical documentation [Cloud Masks](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-1c/cloud-masks)

It appears to be calculated based on reflectance, however there is a known issue as mentioned

> **Two products have been found affected by this [anomaly](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-quality-report)**. The products have very
>   small data coverage and are completely cloudy. The cloud mask is accurate but
>   the cloud coverage metadata is reported as zero. The affected products are
>   30UXB on 11/02/2017 and 50KQL on 12/04/2017.
>   The issue has been analysed and the correction will be deployed in the near
>   future. here is the details:
>
> The Level-1C products embed:
>
> Vector mask (GML format)
>   cloud mask including an indicator specifying cloud type:
>   dense cloud
>   cirrus cloud
>   statistical information: percentage of cloudy pixels and of cirrus pixels in the cloud mask.
>   Cloud Mask (Dense/Cirrus)
>
> The cloud mask enables cloudy and cloud-free pixels to be identified. The mask includes both dense clouds and cirrus clouds with an indicator specifying the cloud type.
>
> Processing is performed with data sampled at 60 m spatial resolution for all spectral bands.
>
> Identification of Dense Clouds
>   The dense clouds, also called opaque clouds, are characterised by a high reflectance in the blue spectral region (B2).
>
> The method used to identify dense cloud pixels is based on B2 reflectance threshold. To avoid false detection, mainly due to snow/cloud confusion, SWIR reflectance in B11 and B12 are also used. Snow and clouds both have a high reflectance in the blue. Cloud reflectance is high in the SWIR, whereas snow presents a low reflectance.
>
> Additional criteria based on B10 reflectance are added to avoid high altitude ice cloud and snow confusion (both having a low reflectance in the SWIR bands B11 and B12). At B10, there is a high atmospheric absorption band and only high altitude clouds are detected. However, this last criterion is only applied after a first detection of cloud pixel in the blue band where cirrus is transparent.
>
> Cirrus Cloud
>   Cirrus clouds are thin, transparent or semi-transparent clouds, forming at high altitudes, approximately 6-7 km above the Earth's surface.
>
> The method of identifying cirrus cloud pixels from dense cloud pixel is based on two spectral criteria:
>
> B10 corresponds to a high atmospheric absorption band: only high altitude clouds can be detected
>   cirrus cloud, being semi-transparent, cannot be detected in the B2 blue band.
>   A pixel with low reflectance in the B2 band and high reflectance in the B10 band has a good probability of being cirrus cloud but this is not a certainty. Some opaque clouds have a low reflectance in the blue and can be identified as cirrus cloud.
>
> To limit false detections (due to high reflectance in the blue or due to the fact that clouds are not spectrally registered), a filter using morphology-based operations is applied on both dense and cirrus masks performing:
>
> erosion, to remove isolated pixels
>   dilatation, to fill the gap and extend clouds.
>   If after morphology operations, a pixel is both dense and cirrus, the dense >cloud mask prevails.
>
> The cloud mask can be set to three values:
>
> 0 is a cloud-free pixel
>   1 is a dense cloud pixel
>   2 is a cirrus cloud pixel.
>   If measurements are not available in one or several bands needed to calculate the cloud mask, the mask value is set to NODATA.
>
> After all filtering steps, the cloud mask is available at a spatial resolution of 60 m. It is then re-sampled at spatial resolutions of 10 m and 20 m for each corresponding spectral band. The re-sampling is not a geometric transformation but a radiometric interpolation.
>
> All these processing steps ensure that a pixel identified as cloud-free is actually cloud-free.

Comment: than cloud coverage should be approximately 100%? (see image preview http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/37/U/DP/2017/10/14/0/preview.jpg )

Comment: I've updated my response.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe there's a quick way to filter such tiles without downloading gml mask?

Comment: Perhaps, your correct. I know you could filter, by Cloud percent, within the search criteria on Copernicus Open Access Hub.

Comment: you can find cloud percentage here ( example iceland) http://apps.sentinel-hub.com/sentinel-playground/?source=S2&lat=64.8923117696475&lng=-18.866443634033203&zoom=12&preset=1_NATURAL_COL0R&layers=B04,B03,B02&maxcc=52&gain=1&gamma=1&time=2015-01-01%7C2017-09-25&atmFilter=&showDates=false

Comment: @Mapperz, on sentinel-hub the issue is ignored. see white part in the center of an image, it has cloud cover = 0 http://apps.sentinel-hub.com/sentinel-playground/?source=S2&lat=46.60463891014406&lng=34.69139099121094&zoom=10&preset=CUSTOM&layers=B04,B03,B02&maxcc=6&gain=1&gamma=1&time=2015-01-01%7C2017-10-15&atmFilter=&showDates=false&evalscript=